# QDesktopServices - как открыть файл, расположенный в локальной сети, в приложении по умолчанию

Tags: c++, qt4

Не получается открыть файл, находящийся в сети, в приложении по умолчанию.
Сервер с `Windows`, машина, с которой запускается проект, также с `Windows`.

Пример c локальным файлом:

```
QString filepath = QObject::trUtf8("C://folder\\ГЛАВНАЯ ПАПКА\\ПАПКА_1\\2_Папка\\1.mkv");
QUrl fileurl = QUrl::fromLocalFile(filepath);
bool result = QDesktopServices::openUrl(fileurl);
if (result == false)
{
   показываю сообщение об ошибке
}
```

В этом случае файл открывается в приложении по умолчанию, результат result = `true`.

Пример c файлом в локальной сети:

```
QString filepath = QObject::trUtf8("//SOMESERVER\\folder\\ГЛАВНАЯ ПАПКА\\ПАПКА_1\\2_Папка\\1.mkv");
QUrl fileurl = QUrl::fromLocalFile(filepath);
bool result = QDesktopServices::openUrl(fileurl);
if (result == false)
{
   показываю сообщение об ошибке
}
```

Файл не открывается, результат = `false`.

Пробовал также вместо `fromLocalFile` использовать `fromUserInput`.

`fileurl.host()` показывает вместо `SOMESERVER` значение `someserver`. Пробовал устанавливать вручную значение `host`, но регистр не учитывается. Пробовал через `ip` тоже. Но файл все равно не открывается.

Предположил, что проблема из-за кириллических символов, или пробелов в пути, или дополнительных точек в названии файла, но путь вида `//SOMESERVER\\folder\\1\\1.mkv` имеет такой же эффект.

`fileurl.errorString()` возвращает `"Invalid URL"": empty"`.

`fileurl.isValid()` возвращает `true`.

`fileurl.isLocalFile()` возвращает `true`.

`fileurl.isEmpty()` возвращает `false`.

```
QFile openfile(filepath);
```

`openfile.exists()` возвращает `true`.

Comment: Замените в имени пути символы `\\ ` на `/`